# A filter method in React isn't working while a map is

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

I am using a ternary check in React. If an item exists, it triggers a .map method, and if it doesn't it triggers a .filter method. The map is working fine, but the filter is not. It is throwing an error saying that an object is not a valid React child, and to use an array. However, to my understanding, it IS an array...

```
 {test.searchTerm === ""
            ? test.users.map((item, index) => (
                <>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                    <td>{item.name.first + " " + item.name.last}</td>
                    <td>{item.email}</td>
                    <td>{item.gender}</td>
                    <td>{item.phone}</td>
                    <td>
                      <img src={item.picture.thumbnail} alt=""></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </>
              ))
            : test.users.filter((item, index) => {
              //console.log(test.users)
                if (
                  test.searchTerm === item.name.first ||
                  test.searchTerm === item.name.last ||
                  test.searchTerm === item.name.first + " " + item.name.last
                ) {

                  return (
                    <>
                      <tr>
                        <td>{index + 1}</td>
                        <td>{item.name.first + " " + item.name.last}</td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                        <td>{item.gender}</td>
                        <td>{item.phone}</td>
                        <td>
                          <img src={item.picture.thumbnail} alt=""></img>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </>
                  );
                }
              })}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is used to create a new array base on the condition. Your filter method should return true for matching element and false other wise. After that you have to map the resulting filtered array. After filter you still have an array of objects.

```js
{test.searchTerm === ""
            ? test.users.map((item, index) => (
                <>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                    <td>{item.name.first + " " + item.name.last}</td>
                    <td>{item.email}</td>
                    <td>{item.gender}</td>
                    <td>{item.phone}</td>
                    <td>
                      <img src={item.picture.thumbnail} alt=""></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </>
              ))
            : test.users.filter((item, index) => {
              //console.log(test.users)
                if (
                  test.searchTerm === item.name.first ||
                  test.searchTerm === item.name.last ||
                  test.searchTerm === item.name.first + " " + item.name.last
                ) {

                  return true;
                }
                return false
              }).map(item => (
                    <>
                      <tr>
                        <td>{index + 1}</td>
                        <td>{item.name.first + " " + item.name.last}</td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                        <td>{item.gender}</td>
                        <td>{item.phone}</td>
                        <td>
                          <img src={item.picture.thumbnail} alt=""></img>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </>
              ))}
```

Comment: so after this bit:  if (
                  test.searchTerm === item.name.first ||
                  test.searchTerm === item.name.last ||
                  test.searchTerm === item.name.first + " " + item.name.last
                )  I should add a .map method?

Comment: Check my example.

Comment: @tzvik15 if someone types ```John``` or ```jOhN``` the search will fail, use ```.toLowerCase()``` or ```.toUpperCase()``` for comparing strings.